# MySQL connection to external database using XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

I've stored a web project (PHP, HTML and CSS). I'm working inside opt/lampp/htdocs XAMPP directory, so I can run the .php files using the web browser. One of those .php files tries to connect to an external server MySQL database, but, when run:

```
mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $userpassword);
```

it displays the following warning.

```
*mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused*
```

I've tried to access the database with phpmyadmin and the corresponding credentials and it works fine.

So the question is: can I perform a msqli_connect to that external database using XAMPP or I should give up?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `mysqli_connect("external_ip", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");`

Comment: @Harikrishnan that's what I tried and triggered the warning. I'll edit my question to include that information. Can you think of anything more? Thanks anyway!

Comment: Maybe you'll need to whitelist your local public ip address on your server.

Comment: Issue this command in terminal and show O/P `telnet server_ip 3306`

Comment: @Harikrishnan 
Trying server_ip...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: Make sure your mysql port is 3306 and whitelist your public IP to connect to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

*Since I cannot comment because of my low points, I am answering here.*

I had faced similar issues before, so sharing my experience. All of the comments have suggested valuable points. These are as follows:

1. Use IP address instead of server name (There may be some DNS cache issue, so it is safe to use IP address).
2. Make sure the IP address you are using is not being blocked by the server's firewall. If possible configure server's firewall to white-list your IP Address.
3. The default MySQL port is 3306. Make sure the firewall is configured for allowing outside connection to the port 3306.

Most importantly, make sure the MySQL server must be configured to accept connections externally. If all of the above settings are configured properly then you should grant external access and all privilege to your MySQL User.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'yourDatabase'.* TO 'yourUserName'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Reference - [Another SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938047/how-to-make-mysql-accept-connections-externally).